# Is it possible for a signal handler to survive after "exec"?

Tags: linux, exec, signals

I wrote a signal handler for a process, and fork() after that, the signal handler will be applied to both parent and child processes. If I replace the child process with "exec", the signal handler is no more.

I know this happens because "exec" call will overwrite the child process address space with it's own.
I just want to know if there is a way to make signal handler work even after "exec" call ?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

No. From the `man` pages:

> execve() does not return on success, and the text, data, bss, and  stack  of  the  calling process  are  overwritten by that of the program loaded.  The program invoked inherits the calling process's PID, and any open file descriptors that are not set to  close  on  exec. Signals  pending  on the calling process are cleared.  Any signals set to be caught by the calling process are reset to their default behaviour. The SIGCHLD  signal  (when  set  to SIG_IGN) may or may not be reset to SIG_DFL.

In fact, if the signal handler were still active after the code had been replaced with some very different code, you could expect all sorts of mayhem when the signal occurred. The signal handler is, after all, just an address to call when something happens (discounting `SIG_IGN` and `SIG_DFL` for now). Who knows what piece of code would be at that address when you replace the entire text segment?

Comment: Nicely explained, thanx Pax.
Actually I had gone through the man-page, Just wanted to know can it be passed through some environment variable or something.

Comment: @Matt for SIG_IGN the child will ignore the signal. SIG_DFL doesn't make sense since it already has the default behaviors.

Comment: Note however that the process signal mask does survive the exec.

Comment: It also conspicuously does not specify what happens to any signals (other than SIGCHLD) set to SIG_IGN.

Comment: Do `SIG_IGN` and `SIG_DFL` survive?

Comment: The ignored and defaulted signal handling is inherited by the child process.  Only handled signals are reset (of necessity) to the default handling, @user8393252.