# Does a parent and child still share signal controls if a child overlays image with exec()?

Tags: c, unix, signals

I think the question says it all. I want to send signals to a child after the child executes another program, but I am unsure if the child and parent still share signals after the image is destroyed and overlayed. I believe the parent and child still share signals and files, is this true?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to signal handler to survive after "exec" ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2333637/is-it-possible-to-signal-handler-to-survive-after-exec)

Comment: Similar questions though I like the wording of mine more. It's nice to read both though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After `exec` the child will still have the same pid and you can send signals to that pid, but any handlers that existed are gone.  The child would have to set up explicit handlers itself.

Comment: Thanks that makes perfect sense, can I send a signal to all children at once?

Comment: There's a concept called "process groups" which addresses many issues with signals (such as "what process gets SIGINT when you hit ^C").  If your children were all in a process group you could kill them all with `killpg()`.  Practically speaking there won't be any real difference between that and just looping over the list yourself.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I think that will be helpful. If I can't work out 2 different groups I will try looping through all of them.